# Radstudio and Interbase license issue?

Tags: ios, delphi, interbase

I had my RadStudio setup all working and have created a very simple mobile app for android that uses IBLite to grab some data.  For business reasons I had to leave the project and move on to other things.  So I come back to Radstudio thinking I can just pick up where I left off.

I notice there is an update for the product so I apply the changes and then open up my previous project. From there things get very strange.  I can build and deploy to android and the project still works.  If I deploy to IOS simulator again no problem and everything works fine.  As soon as I try to deploy to a device I get the following compiler error:-

[DCC Error] E2597 ld: library not found for -libtogo
(This is an outstanding question on Embarcadero Developer Forum)

Which looks to me like a problem with the licence file. So I try to manually add it to the deployment but still get the error.  So I decided to park my project and go back to the IOS IBLite tutorial from the Embarcadero website.  I get to the stage where I want to drop an sqlconnection to the form and connect to the database... No joy it comes up with unavailable database which I thought might be a licensing issue or the fact the IB Server was not running. So I double checked the latter and sure enough it is running as a windows service and I can use IBConsole to connect to it.

So I drop trying to create a mobile application and try to create a desktop app that connects to the dbdemos database.  No luck, the ide still states unavailable database...

So to my question?

How do I get radstudio to pick up the license for Interbase and particulary IBLIte for IOS?

I have searched online and on the EDF and have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: i think when it comes about LICENSES you have to use official channels, rather than users peer forum. http://support.embarcadero.com/

Comment: Yes I did have a question with them which they answered with uninstall and reinstall.. That does not work.

Comment: Borland/CodeGear/EMBT support frequently preferred to err on bad side. But again, except for our sympathies there is little we can do to help you.

Comment: Saw your on G+, glad that you found another approach for  mobile. What about desktop,  then I think no Interbase just has no appeal after there is Firebird. Right now we use IB license sheets for drafting development notes,  because they just do not worth anything else and FB community is much more vibrant than EMBT would ever be

Comment: Fortunately the only desktop stuff I do goes through a REST server so I do not have to worry too much about databases, other than putting some data in an in memory dataset for the user to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/IBLite_and_IBToGo_Test_Deployment_Licensing_in_RAD_Studio_XE5) link.
IBREDISTDIR environment variable should be properly configurated with the directory containing library folders and licenses.

RAD Studio links statically libibtogo.a probably this file is missing. This file usually is into ($BDS)/lib/iosDevice/debug path